# Plotly Python - Add Label leader lines in pie chart

Tags: python, plotly

I am looking for a nicer solution to add label leader lines in a piechart with plotly. Using "fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')" looks ugly.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Asia'")
fig = px.pie(df, values='pop', names='country')
fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
fig.show()
fig.write_image("fig1.png")
```

[image]

i am looking for a solution looks like this:
[image]

thanks for ideas!

Comment: Perhaps the current method would look more visually appealing if you grouped all values under 2% in a category called "Others" rather than trying to display all of these very small values.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i choose this as an example, but in my "real code problem". i can not group to others.

Comment: @Alex Why not exactly, can't you just change your dataframe so that categories below a certain threshold are classified as `'other'`? For the example in the question you could limit the categories by the population arbitrarily like this for example `df = df[df["pop"] > 50000000]`. The same idea could apply to your actual code as well couldn't it?

Comment: because, in my case, it is important to see the percent of each part of the pie. and i interestest if there is an other way to display the label leader lines